# Why two hosts can't contact with each other directly use their IP address?

Tags: networking

In a global internet, for two machines on the same subnet to communicate, they  need to know each other's physical address. So, the source machine has to map  the internet address of the destination into a physical address. Why is this  address mapping important? Couldn't the two machines just communicate using their internet addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Because the goal of the Internet is to connect different types of subnets together. It is local decision of each subnet how to organize addressing on this subnet and how to deliver packets on it. Thus layer 3 (that uses IP addresses) delivers packets up to the subnet, and then the subnet (layer 2) decides how to deliver packets within itself.

Mapping, that you are describing is done for Ethernet-type subnets. One can potentially have different types of subnet protocols which do addresses differently. Although, now, almost everyting falls under Ethernet-family.